# Previous radiobutton selected

Tags: android, radio-button

I got a radiogroup with 2 radiobutton (M and F). 
When I select one it saves correcty on the sqlite db.
If it was a editTest I would do something like

```
name.setText(cursor.getString(1));
```

Yes I have to see what is on that position, but here I have 2 radiobutton... What can I do so when visiting that activity again it will be the choice picked before?

I'm doing like this:

```
rad= (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
rad.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) 
            {
                checkedRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId);
                text = checkedRadioButton.getText().toString();                
            }
        }           
                );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you assign each option a tag, you can save the current value using:

```
savedValue = radioButton.getTag()
```

then you can restore it using:

```
((RadioButton)radioGroup.findViewWithTag(savedValue)).setChecked(true);
```

Comment: This helped me because i was saving the string of that radiobutton and now im saving the id of that (its weird number but..), for the user looks good not so much on the sqlite. Thanks!!

Comment: actually, i don't know what i was thinking when i wrote that; the id can change between versions of your app. i've updated the answer to give better advice. use the "tag" attribute instead; this is a much better idea.

Comment: It looks better to do that way.. But, the `savedValue` is an object and I'm getting some problems inserting

Comment: if you assign the `tag` attribute in the layout editor at design-time, then it will always be a `String` at runtime and you can just cast it.